# Error on installing OpenStack

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I'm going to install new OpenStack infrastructure as below. The instructions are located at https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#single-multi-large-cluster . 3 HP server DL380 G7, each one has 2 CPU and 128 GB RAM, Ubuntu 22.04 with the latest updates. For controller I have installed the requirements and do the 2 steps as shown below.

```
sudo snap install openstack --channel 2023.1
sunbeam prepare-node-script | bash -x && newgrp snap_daemon
```

These two commands were done successfully with root account,
but on running the 3rd command it occurs in an error and prompts:

```
Timed out while waiting for model 'openstack' to be ready
Error: Timed out while waiting for model 'openstack' to be ready
```

[image]